# Toggleclass on clicking menu link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a hamburger button ".btn" - when clicked, it displays a dropdown menu with three menu items. ".menu" is display: none ; ".show" is display: block

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".btn").on("click",function(){
          $('.menu').toggleClass("show");
        });
</script>
```

What I'd like is for the class to toggle from 'show' back to 'menu' upon clicking on any of the menu items - given they are anchor links to lower sections of the page. I've tried adding a class to each menu item and implementing the reverse logic:

```
$(".menuLink").on("click",function(){
              $('.show').toggleClass("menu");
            });
```

^ Sadly this doesn't work, and displays all the links overlaying the menubar in un-styled fashion (blue links).

HTML

```
            <div class="menu">
                <a href="#product">THE PRODUCT</a>
                <a href="#story">THE STORY</a>
                <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 0px;
}

.menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ddc170;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 15pt;
}

.show {
    display: block;
    max-height: 500px;
    background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.9);
}
```

Any help would be wonderful. Thanks.

Comment: did you add jquery library?add jquery library and than try to run the code if still you face the problem .than let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `.text()` method to set the text of the menu link depending on its current text.

```css
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 0px;
}

.menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ddc170;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 15pt;
}

.show {
    display: block;
    max-height: 500px;
    background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="menuLink">Show</a>
<div class="menu">
     <a href="#product">THE PRODUCT</a>
     <a href="#story">THE STORY</a>
     <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
</div>
<script>
$(".menuLink").on("click",function(){
    $(".menu").toggleClass("show");
    $(this).text()=="Show"?$(this).text("Hide"):$(this).text("Show");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#show").click(function(){
        $(".menu").toggle();
      });

     });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="menu">
            <a href="#product">THE PRODUCT</a>
            <a href="#story">THE STORY</a>
            <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
        </div>
   <button id="show">show</button>
</body>
```

at the place of button you can use simple toggle icon